# How to make HTML download link for .exe file?

Tags: html, download, executable

I’m in the process of building a website and I want to make a link where people can download a file called `test.exe`. I’ve tried things like this:

```html
<a href=“test.exe” download></a>
```

But none of them download the file. It just sends me to a page that doesn’t exist. What’s the correct way to write it?

(Note: `test.exe` is located on my desktop)

Comment: That should work.  You can try `download=“download”`.  You might have to use a path reference depending on where the file is.  Does right click “save as” work?

Comment: test.exe will have to be in a Directory above your document root

Comment: Thank you, I will try all of them right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it worked on my website for a PDF file. I'm not sure why it shouldn't with any other file extension.

```
<form method="get" action="test.exe">
    <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

Note that "test.exe" needs to be in the same directory as your page.html or the path needs to be defined i.e. "downloads/test.exe".

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
<a href="path/to/file.exe" target="_blank">Download Link </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend moving the EXE file to the same folder where you have your .html file stored.

Then you can just use:

```
<html>
<body>

    <a href="file.exe">Download my exe file</a>

</body>
</html>
```